# Find values of the parameter a so that equation has equal roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

$x^2+2a\sqrt{a^2-3}x+4=0$

My final result was 2 and -0.5. Was it correct?

Comment: how did you get that?

Comment: Put a=-0.5 into the equation. What do you find?

Comment: I get $\pm 2$, if we are working in the reals.  Additional solution $\pm i$ if working over the complex numbers.

Comment: I calculated determinant $b^2 - 4ac$ where $a = 1, b = 2a\sqrt{a^2-3}, c = 4$ then used the quadric equation to calculate the value of $a$.

Comment: Yes, a discriminant calculation is right, we get a quadratic in $a^2$, solve. Some minor thing went wrong in the solution process if you got $-1/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a pair of equal roots, we need to have  $2a\sqrt{a^2 - 3} = 4$.

$$\begin{align} 2a\sqrt{a^2-3}=4 &\iff \sqrt{a^4 - 3a^2}=  2 \\ \\ &\iff a^4 - 3a^2 = 4\\ \\ & \iff a^4 - 3a^2 - 4 = 0 \\ \\ & \iff (a^2 - 4)(a^2 +1) = 0\end{align} $$

$a^2 + 1 \geq 1$, so can never be zero. So we solve  $$a^2 - 4 = (a+2)(a-2)=0$$ $$ \iff a = -2 \text{ or } a = 2$$